# AR images not working inside the WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, augmented-reality, wkwebview

Here is the AR Quick Look website from Apple docs - https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/

If I go to this website in the Safari browser on my iPhone 8, then everything is working correctly. I can tap any of the 3D model and place it inside the Augmented Reality.

However, if I view the same website in the WKWebView, then the AR models are not working correctly. I am not able to tap any model and place it inside the AR.

For the comparison I am attaching screenshots from the Safari browser and from the WKWebView

Safari

[image: Safari]

WKWebView

[image: WKWebView]

As you can see in WKWebView, the AR icon is not even showing up.

Does anyone knows why AR images are not working inside the WKWebView?

I will be very glad for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a tweet from 2018 suggesting that WKWebView does not support AR Quick Look. You can find it [here](https://twitter.com/lDavixl/status/1004834762849058816). The [WebKit](https://webkit.org/blog/8421/viewing-augmented-reality-assets-in-safari-for-ios/) website also suggests that.

Most probably SFSafariController should be used instead.